# Uglify weird characters spaces

Tags: javascript, webpack, uglifyjs

I'm using @easy-webpack/config-uglify for my production setup on a React project. I'm noticing in certain random characters showing up in my strings--usually where there's a space or an &nbsp; character. Is there anything I can do in my uglify configuration to make these weird characters go away?
[image: weird characters]

My Uglify configuration:

```js
require('@easy-webpack/config-webpack')({
  mangle: {
    except: ['joint', '$', 'require', 'webpackJsonp'],
    keep_fnames: true,
    screw_ie8: true
}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your `index.html`:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```